# rdiff-backup remote schema does not take input

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, rdiff-backup

I'm trying to set up rdiff-backup between my windows host machine and my remote linux machine. I'm using Windows 8.1. SSH and rdiff-backup is indeed within the PATH environment variablle...

With the below command:

`rdiff-backup --print-statistics --override-chars-to-quote --remote-schema "ssh -C %s -p1019 rdiff-backup --server" --exclude "**.dropbox**" --exclude "desktop.ini" "C:/Users/Adam/Dropbox" pi@192.168.0.5::/mnt/disk1/Adam/Dropbox`

I recieve the following results:

`ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.5 port 22: Connection refused`
`Fatal Error: Truncated header string (problem probably being originated remotely)`

`Couldnt start up the remote connection by executing ssh -C pi@192.168.0.5 rdiff-backup --server`

You would assume by that output that formatting of the command is incorrect. Although I must assure you I've read the manual and many examples online and this format is correct. As you can see from the command I've depicted `-p1019`. So Why is attempting port 22?! Even when I do the following command:

`rdiff-backup --print-statistics --override-chars-to-quote --exclude "**.dropbox**" --exclude "desktop.ini" "C:/Users/Adam/Dropbox" pi@192.168.0.5::/mnt/disk1/Adam/Dropbox`

(Difference being that the arguments given after `--remote-schema` are no longer present) I still get the exact same output. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this succeed `rdiff-backup --print-statistics --override-chars-to-quote --exclude "**.dropbox**" --exclude "desktop.ini" "C:/Users/Adam/Dropbox" pi@192.168.0.5::/mnt/disk1/Adam/Dropbox` ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in the question asked. The second command should have been what you suggested. However, just to confirm anyway - that command does not work, even with port 22 opened. It returns `Fatal Error: Switches missing or wrong number of arguments" Thank you for your help, I apologise for my late one, @clement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The `--override-chars-to-quote` just wasn't any of it. Once I removed this AND added an extra `%` to `%s` so it became `%%s` my problems were solved.

I found this out by removing all the options, adding one at a time and trying all sorts of combinations until the error occurred. I narrowed it down to `--override-chars-to-quote` and then when I did, rdiff-backup spat out another error message: `No arguments given`. So I looked at what command was being entered and it was the `%` not being escaped (or whatever), and I remember reading elsewhere that including another `%` typically fixes some issues when using `--remote-schema`.

So it's official. `--override-chars-to-quote` just doesn't work. Either that or my understanding of the option is wrong - I'm transferring from a Windows file system to a Linux one. NTFS to VFAT (according to `fdisk -l` anyway).